# Ansible Role include

Tags: ansible

I have a task that can be used by several roles. I added it to lib/mycommontask.yml

On my playbook on roles/my-project/tasks/main.yml I have:

```
--
- include: lib/mycommontask.yml
  vars:
    project: my-project
    version: "{{ version }}"

- name: ...
```

When I run the task, I receive the following error

```
ERROR: Syntax Error while loading YAML script, /home/lg/src/devops/deploy/roles/my-porject/tasks/main.yml
Note: The error may actually appear before this position: line 2, column 10

--
- include: lib/mycommontask.yml
         ^
```

Can I include inside a role task? How should I do that?

Answer (score 4):

For your playbook to be a valid YAML file the 1st line must contain 3 dashes `---`, not 2.